# Fiber — Intel x520 SFP+ with Mikrotik CRS305-1G-4S+IN SFP+ troubleshooting

Tags: networking, network-adapter, fiber

- I have an [Intel 82599 X520](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Supermicro-AOC-STGN-i2S-Dual-Port-10G-SFP-Intel-82599-X520-DA2-Network-Adapter/265082261270) (dual SFP+) network adapter in [my motherboard](https://www.asrock.com/MB/Intel/Z490%20Pro4/index.asp).
- I have a [HP Procurve 1410-24g](https://h10057.www1.hp.com/ecomcat/hpcatalog/specs/provisioner/99/J9561A.htm) switch with SFP ports.
- I have a [Mikrotik CRS305-1G-4S+IN](https://mikrotik.com/product/crs305_1g_4s_in) switch with SFP+ ports
- I have [A7EL-SN85-ADMA](https://ao-inc.com/images/uploads/products/80-21-0314_A7EL-SN85-ADMA_008.pdf) transceivers
- I believe I have an IBM 12R9914 (OFNP, MMF, LC-LC, orange) fiber optic cable. It was given to me for free, so I do not know where it came from.

I am using Windows 10, 64 bit. In the device manager, I see the dual SFP+ ports as "Intel(R) 82599 10 Gigabit Dual Port Network Connection," so I believe my NIC is installed in my computer correctly. I tried plugging the transceiver into the x520 NIC and into one of the SFP ports on the HP switch, and I plugged the fiber optic cable into both. Nothing seemed to happen (the respective status lights did not light up). I tried flipping the fiber optic on one side as someone had suggested, but no luck. I am guessing that this is due to the HP switch port being SFP and not SFP+ (thus needing a SFP transceiver). Also, people online say that HP hardware is picky...

Somewhere online, I read that the Intel x520 NIC is agnostic when it comes to transceivers and motherboard interfaces, so my understanding is that there is no problem with the NIC. I also read that the Mikrotik switch is also agnostic when it comes to using other vendors' transceivers, so I bought one and decided to use that instead of the HP Procurve 1410-24g switch with SFP ports. Also, the Mikrotik switch has SFP+ ports, so I believe that eliminates the possibility of needing 1G SFP transceivers.

Even so, it still does not work. The respective lights on the NIC or Mikrotik switch did not light up. Are the transceivers or fiber optic cable the issue here? I am not sure if it is a compatibility issue, due to all the different companies and manufacturers involved.  I do not have experience with fiber...

Side note: I have a different machine that has a x520 NIC, and it was pretty much plug-and-play using a Direct Attach Copper (DAC) cable with a Mikrotik SFP+ switch. However, I do not have access to that DAC cable, so I cannot try it with this equipment yet...

Comment: I removed my answer, your SFP+ datasheet states that om-1 (orange) cable can be used to up to roughly 100ft. If you don't have a tester for the fiber you can use a bright led flashlight on one end to see if it has light continuity to the other end. The other test you can do with out tools (if the cable has continuity) is making a loopback with one out of the two strands. Remove the individual fibers from the plastic bridges, and take a single fiber and loop it back to the same SFP+. Essentially you are looping TX back to RX on the same module. Do you get a link light with the loopback?

Comment: Also, google cleaning the LC terminations. If they aren't clean it will severely dampen the signal. (Probably making the 33m limitation for these modules much smaller) let me know how that works out.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart thanks for the suggestions. Before I try that and try to determine whether the "problem" is with the fiber optic cable itself, I wanted to make sure that the transceivers I have are compatible with the x520 NIC and the Mikrotik switch. 

Online, some people said that the x520 only works with Intel branded transceivers, while others say it should be OK, and some people suggest using software to enable support (like https://www.rymnd.org/blog/2020/unsupported-sfp-intel-x520/).

Comment: It looks like that card does in fact have a whitelist for SFP+ modules. All hope is not lost though, give this a read over. https://forums.servethehome.com/index.php?threads/patching-intel-x520-eeprom-to-unlock-all-sfp-transceivers.24634/

Comment: The link I had sent in my previous comment refers to that same link! If I want to ask about doing that on my Windows machine, should I be making a new post? I am not sure how to get the driver information (e.g. `eno1`) for my x520 card...

Comment: Probably a bootable Linux usb would be your best bet. If what that person says is true, after going back to windows, it should work with the drivers you have already.

Comment: I meant to ask about the actual commands I would run. I have Ubuntu installed via Windows Subsystem for Linux on my Windows machine, so I have access to a bash terminal to run the commands in with sudo privilege. However, I am not sure how to obtain the actual driver identifier for my x520 card so that I can try out the commands the article suggests.

Comment: At this point it may be useful to either edit this question to reflect what you know you need to do, or delete it and ask it as a whole new question. I think it will get better attention from the community as a whole new one honestly. I wouldn't use virtualization, or emulation here... If something goes wrong you'll most likely brick/kill the card. Live usb, while admittedly is slow to boot up, will have native full control of the hardware and direct hardware access. I can't say with your setup if that's the case with the Linux subsystem for windows. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: From your previous comment: **lspci -nn** should bring up what you need.